# When I go in to rendered view, my object gets this weird shadow pattern

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shadows

This is the shadow problem I get. There are no problems in either solid nor material view.

Picture:

[image]

Blend file:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's because you have triangles on the sides of your roof that have vertices that are in the middle of the top faces, making them N-gon's (faces with more than 4 vertices). Blender does not like Tris or N'gon's for shading purposes. However, since the shape is so simple, you can get away with using a Decimate Modifier set to "Planar" to clean the topology up.

[image: Decimate]

This being said, this method still leaves triangles on the sides (albeit larger) - you might want to make the roof truly quad-based by deleing the top and side faces (except for the "back"), then extrude the front edge on the Z axis just a little, then connect the top 2 edges to make a face (F), then the edge loops on the side and also make faces.

[image: Extrude]

Note- pardon the pink - it looks like you forgot to pack your texture.

Comment: thank you that cleared some of the issues. i do still have some issues with my lighting though, see the edited picture if you care to help some more.

Comment: Ok. I'm working on it -  I notice your Roughness, Displacement and Normal Map images are set to sRGB - They should be set to non-color. Also, your displacement image should be run through the height input of a displacement node - but those still don't fix it. Still trying things - EDIT - it's definitely something to do with your Normal Map image - disconnect it from the input and you'll see.

Comment: thank you that worked, and when i changed the normal map from tangent space to object space it completely fixed it. thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It often happens when you import the files too, usually if they don't have the sharp edges then the object looks like it has some weird shadows when you move in 3D view or any view. Make the edges *Mark Sharp*, and recalculate normals, maybe it will solve the problem.

Before
[image]

After
[image]

As you can see in the above examples, that's how I solved it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.